# How can i loop WordPress specific post

Tags: wordpress

How can i loop `WordPress` post like-

- Last one.
- 3rd last one from below.

As far as I know I can select last and first one by adding order by `asc/desc` but i cant figure out 2nd one.

Comment: You are try to arrange your blog in custom way.

Comment: is there solutions?

Comment: You can try any plugin

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/ Try this you can drag and drop your post

Comment: i did not ask for it bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try an offset of recent posts with a limit of 1? Like this:

```
$args = array(
'numberposts' => 1, // only return 1 post
'offset' => 2, // select the third item found
'orderby' => 'post_date', // field for order by
'order' => 'DESC', //DESC for 3th most recent, ASC for third oldest post
'post_type' => 'post', // could be any post type, remove if you want all post types
'post_status' => 'publish' // only show published posts, remove if you want all even trashed
);

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Glad to be of help!